# Input value undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAHmG.png)im trying to create a function which add users based on input value (user and pass), but i get **undefined** value

```js
let button = document.getElementById("register");

var dataBase = [];

button.addEventListener("click", function (){
      let user = document.getElementsByClassName("username").value;
      let pass = document.getElementsByClassName("password").value;
      dataBase.push({user,pass});
      console.log(dataBase)
})
```

```html
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"/>
<input class="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"/>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("username")` returns an array of elements. You need to specify the index to access the relevant element. document.getElementsByClassName("username")[0]. 

You can give ids to elements and access their values by `document.getElementById("username").value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to know that `getElementsByClassName()` returns the HTMLCollection. And that's why `.value` return **undefined**.

Best practice for getting the data by applying id to element and get it by `getElementById()`.

So your code will be:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (){
      let user = document.getElementById("myUser").value;
      let pass = document.getElementById("myPass").value;
      dataBase.push({user,pass});
      console.log(dataBase)
})
```

And html is:

```
<input class="username" id="myUser" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"/>
<input class="password" id="myPass" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"/>
```

But if you still want to get the value using the `getElementsByClassName()` then here is the solution:

```
let user = document.getElementsByClassName("username")[0].value;
let pass = document.getElementsByClassName("password")[0].value;
```

As they return the collection and assume that there is no element of that same class available in HTML DOM.

Comment: Nice answer, I would say that `.querySelector()` would be a better alternative to `getElementsByClassName()[0]`, as `querySelector()` will stop traversing the DOM once it finds the element, whereas getElementsByClassName will continue to traverse the entire DOM for all elements, even though you just need to use the first one.

Comment: Thank you!. Yes, `querySelector()` also useful in this case.

Comment: now everything make sense, thanks you so much for effort

Answer (score 1):

Use this code below

```js
let button = document.getElementById("register");

var dataBase = [];

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (){

      let user = document.getElementById("username").value;
      let pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
      
      dataBase.push({user,pass});
      console.log(dataBase)
})
```

```html
<input class="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"/>
<input class="password" id="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input value undefined? because `getElementsByClassName()` return `array` of element to element so to get first element `document.getElementsByClassName("password")[0].value`

```js
let button = document.getElementById("register");

var dataBase = [];

button.addEventListener("click", function (){
      let user = document.getElementsByClassName("username")[0].value;
      let pass = document.getElementsByClassName("password")[0].value;
      dataBase.push({user,pass});
      console.log(dataBase)
})
```

```html
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"/>
<input class="password" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"/>

<button id="register" >register</button>
```

Comment: WORKs!, thanks you so mutch!

Comment: @Negatiiv you are most welcome

Comment: But it won't work if there is an element of the same class name above this username and password fields in HTML DOM.

Comment: @YatinjSutariya Thanks. yes, it will not work if more than one element with the same class then need to use input id and find using getElementById.